# How do you make custom item/skill builds in Dota 2 Reborn?

Tags: dota-2

The title pretty much says it all.  In the previous client, I was able to make custom item/skill builds for my heroes and save them to load in games. How can I do this in reborn?  Also is there anywhere to just view the items, like in the old client?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the [hero build guides](http://steamcommunity.com/app/570/guides/?browsefilter=trend&filetype=12&requiredtags[]=english) on Steam which you can subscribe to and use in-game?

Comment: yeah, i dont really care about publishing them, but i used to be able to make them in Dota client and then use them in my games

Comment: I too would like to know. I've looked around a lot for this and was unable to find it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [this site](http://www.dota2.com/workshop/builds/create) to create hero builds once you are logged in. It is an official dota 2 site and i have used it to update my build to 6.85.

However there are some things broken, the most obvious one is that you cannot add comments to items or skill builds. But if it is only for you and a few friends then it should be sufficient until they add something more.

You can also view the items/heroes there, but there is no way to view the items in the reborn client. If you want to check items somewhere, i suggest the [dota wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Items). It is updated a lot and contains a lot of information.

Comment: You can add comments to items, just click the item after it's placed on the build. It is very buggy, though.

Comment: To add the comment that the item/skill you need to tab to it, then tab to the save button to save it without the box bugging

Answer (score 1):

When you open the shop the recommended item build should automatically appear. Above this small tab is a icon for a pencil. Click on it and you can drag items into the tab under the "early, core, luxury" tabs. Remember to click on the pencil icon again to save the build.